# Crash handling in swiftUI

Tags: ios, error-handling, swiftui, crash

Newcomer in ios with some android experience . I would like to handle app crashes (if possible in ios) in swiftui like i do in android ie forward the user to a custom View.
Basically , when an lethal  error occurs in java it is caught and user forwarded .

Here is the code in java

```
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {

    StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();

    exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
    System.err.println(stackTrace);
    Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, myActivityClass);
    String s = stackTrace.toString();

    intent.putExtra("error", s);
    myContext.startActivity(intent);

    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    System.exit(0);


}
```

Comment: There isn't a way to recover from fatal exceptions in iOS.  You can use `do/try/catch` to catch exceptions from functions that can `throw`, but if your app causes a fatal exception, such as exceeding an array bound, then it is going to be killed.  Analytics packages, like Crashlytics and others, can capture the exception and stack trace and send it to a server where you can analyse it, but the app will be terminated on the device.  You could implement your own code to do this, but it probably isn't worth it.  Focus on writing code that doesn't crash :)

Comment: Thanx a lot,sad to learn this but somehow i m not too surprised with ios

Comment: Well, it has much the same effect as the Java code in your question; The app exits.  Showing an incomprehensible (to the average user) stack trace before it does so doesn't really improve the experience.

Comment: With this code, implementing an uncaught error catch in each activity , i manage to  forward to the activity i want . This is totally transparent for the user  who wouldnt notice any crash  if he wasn t told (could force an auto restart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer thanx to Paulw11.
Any uncaught error will ead to crash , no possibility to handle the way it does crash